# Matching and extracting values from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to find matching values in a pandas dataframe. Once a match is found I want to perform some operations on the row of the dataframe.

Currently I'm using this Code:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'child_id': [1,2,5,4,7,8,9,10],
 'parent_id': [3,4,1,3,11,6,12,13],
 'content': ["thon","pan","py","das","ten","sor","js","on"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns = ("content_child", "content_parent"))

for i in range(len(df)):

        for j in range(len(df)):

            if str(df['child_id'][j]) == str(df['parent_id'][i]):
                content_child = str(df["content"][i])

                content_parent = str(df["content"][j])

                s = pd.Series([content_child, content_parent], index=['content_child', 'content_parent'])
                df2 = df2.append(s, ignore_index=True)
            else:
                pass

 print(df2)
```

This Returns:

```
  content_child content_parent
0           pan            das
1            py           thon
```

I tried using df.loc functions, but I only succeed in getting either Content from child or Content from parent:

```
df.loc[df.parent_id.isin(df.child_id),['child_id','content']]
```

Returns:

```
      child_id content
1         2     pan
2         5      py
```

Is there an fast alternative to the loop I have written?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use just `join` data frames with condition if left part `child_id` is equal to right part `parent_id`.

```
df.set_index('parent_id').join(df.set_index('child_id'), rsuffix='_').dropna()
```

this code will create two data tables with ids `parent_id` and `child_id`. Then join them as usual SQL join. After all drop NaN values and get `content` column. Which is what you want. There are 2 content columns. one of them is parent content and second is child content.

Comment: The performance will same If use left join. The question was to speed up the code. This method is much more readable, also do not require additional operations.

Answer (score 1):

For improve performance use `map`:

```
df['content_parent'] = df['parent_id'].map(df.set_index('child_id')['content'])
df = (df.rename(columns={'content':'content_child'})
        .dropna(subset=['content_parent'])[['content_child','content_parent']])
print (df)
  content_child content_parent
1           pan            das
2            py           thon
```

Or `merge` with default inner join:

```
df = (df.rename(columns={'child_id':'id'})
        .merge(df.rename(columns={'parent_id':'id'}), 
              on='id', 
              suffixes=('_parent','_child')))[['content_child','content_parent']]
print (df)
  content_child content_parent
0            py           thon
1           pan            das
```